# Python in Set Checking Bag of Words

Tags: python, performance

I have a text processing script that needs to check if a word is in a bag of words. I have to do this many (10000s) of times. I would think that the most efficient way to do this would be to define the set of words that I am checking for `wordBag = set(['these', 'are', 'my', 'words'])` and then do `if word in wordBag:`. I looked at the documentation and this is average case O(1) and worst case O(n). Is this just due to chaining in hashsets? Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: You are correct. Best case: O(1) -> No collision. Worst case: O(n) -> All entries hash to the same location and you follow n chains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the size of your set of words. For any non-huge amount (probably up to tens of thousands) your approach is absolutely fine and totally pythonic. Simplicity is a virtue!

If you do have a vast amount of words in your bag, a [prefix-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) (or "trie") approach will likely be best, for that you can check PyPI for existing implementations ([example](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/patricia-trie)).

**EDIT:** The `O(n)` worst-case is only in the case of huge numbers of hash collisions as you suspected, but that's not usually a problem in practice. In any case, I would go with the simplest approach first and only look at more advanced solutions if you actually have performance or memory issues.